# I have to take from db every row that has

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to pick up from my db every row with the field "level" that is between mylevel-5 and mylevel+5. But im new to php and sql and i dont know how to write the query... Can u help me?

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    $nickname = $_SESSION['nick'];
}else{
    header('location:index.php');
}

include('connection.php');

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE nickname = '$nickname'"); 
$rissql = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$mylevel = $rissql['Level'];

$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE Level >= $mylevel-5 && Level <= $mylevel+5 order by rand() limit 1");
$rissql2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2);
$count=mysql_num_rows($rissql2);

if($count > 0)
{
    header('location:fightok.php');
}
else
{
    header('location:fightno.php');
}

?>
```

Comment: This will help you: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp if you still cant manage it, post here again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting your limit before writing the query:

```
$lower = $myLevel - 5;
$upper = $myLevel + 5;
```

Then re-write your query using these values and replace && with AND for MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE Level >= $lower AND Level <= $upper ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
```

or using BETWEEN

```
SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE Level BETWEEN $lower AND $upper ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
```

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: consider answering using the between method. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

Comment: Good call. Thanks. Updated answer.